# Can I install Windows 7 OEM SystemBuilder on a MacBook Air?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, macbook, oem

I just bought a new MacBook Air for university and would really like to have a Windows 7 installation accessible. Now if I use Boot Camp for it, there's always the same problem:

I set the size for the partitions (tried different sizes, doesn't matter) and press *Install*, which then continues. After the partitioning is finished, the MacBook Air restarts – and the screen turns black. It is still lit, so it's not off.

So I called the Apple Support and they told me it's impossible to use an OEM SystemBuilder Version for this installation and I've got to get the retail one. So, my question is: Is there a way to install Windows 7 on the new MacBook Air, using an OEM SystemBuilder CD?

Comment: Install legally or technically?

Comment: It's a legal Windows, so yes, I need the 'technical' instruction how to do it, because it doesn't seem to work the way it should/would with a retail version.

Comment: Don't wanna pressure anyone, but if there's a way I'd really appreciate a how-to, because otherwise I'll have to buy another, more expansive Windows 7.

Comment: If OEM it is not legal.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to migrate Windows 7 OEM from HP machine to a virtual machine in Mac OS X Lion on Macbook Air with Parallels 6 by using Parallels Transporter Agent to migrate to an external hard drive, then creating a disk image from that drive on the Mac with Disk Utility, then creating the Windows virtual machine from the .dmg. I'm not familiar with Boot Camp, but I wonder if you could do something like that.

I want to add a variation of this question: I want to try this out with Fusion 4, but it doesn't look like Fusion will let me, and it won't migrate the HP Win 7 directly. I already took the Parallels off because it was taking up too much memory, so I can't convert directly from the Parallels VM. I could reinstall the Parallels VM and then convert, but would like to know if I can do this directly.

I don't intend to use the HP if I can get Windows working on my Mac. I don't use it that much, and I can't afford/ don't think I should have to pay $199 for another license when I already paid for the one I have.

Comment: HI Miz_mdk, it would be worth posting your question part of this answer as a seperate question. That way it will get attention all on its own.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment then an answer.